# Invalid end of sector signature: 0xB3E1 (SD Card Formatter)

Tags: partitioning, formatting, sd-card

After "flashing" Ubuntu Mate onto an SD Card using Etcher, Etcher successfully verified the data, but since it refused to boot on my Raspberry Pi, I decided to retry the flash.
I deleted all the partitions created by Etcher (from the image), and retried.
This time, Etcher couldn't verify that the SD card had been written properly (failed *after* verification, not write) and Raspberry Pi crashed during boot.
I wasn't even able to reformat the SD card. (I was able to delete the partitions, even create a new one, but unable to format it with FAT)

I tried the [SD Card Formatter](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/), but it stopped with the error that's in the heading of this question.

Any idea what I can do to fix it?

Comment: Ever figure this one out? having same issue.

Comment: Seems the card was dead. Later found out it was a counterfeit Kingston card (the reflective QC sticker should've tipped me off at the start), which is made even scarier considering I bought it from a reputable retailer.

Comment: So I just got a new sdcard (from Amazon this time), plugged it in to SDcard reader on my CalDigit. Tried to flash again and it did the EXACT same thing. I feel like i'm taking crazy pills. These are literally brand new cards. I'm starting to wonder if it's the sd card reader on my CalDigit screwing it up?

Comment: It's likely the card reader then.